# .getStartTime() not a function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

how do i get .getStartTime to work?

i'm using the CalendarEvent class, and .getStartTime is listed under this class (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getStartTime())

but when i try to run the following code, i get `TypeError: Cannot find function getStartTime in object CalendarEvent.`

```
function test() {
  var TA =CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("CalendarName")[0].getEvents(startDt, endDt);
  var starting = TA.getStartTime();
  Logger.log(starting);
  return;
};
```

what am i doing wrong? i can't figure it out, all the tutorials i found online indicates that this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [getEvents(Date,Date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date)) it returns CalendarEvent[] .

So , you're trying to call a method on an entire array, instead of a particular CalendarEvent object.

Simply use `TA[0].getStartTime()` or whichever event you'd like.