# Type error getting Calendar event dates in Apps Script: 'TypeError when attempting "getStartTime()"'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm coding a script to modify select Google Calendar events by setting their start & end date/times to today. However, I'm stuck due to a type error every time I attempt to get the date or time of a calendar event - such as by using "**event.getTime()**", which results in "**TypeError: Cannot find function getStartTime in object**" (see line 19 of my sample code).

I have enabled both the Calendar API and the Google Apps API, and have authorized the script to modify my calendar.

My code to select and retrieve the relevant calendar events works fine. Based on the error text, however, I'm apparently not getting the events as objects, and I can't pinpoint what I need to correct. I've spent the better part of 2-3 days scouring Stack Overflow (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489432/getstarttime-not-a-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261612/apps-scripts-getstarttime-doesnt-work) post), Apps Script documentation, API references, and many other relevant resources for solutions or examples, and attempting all variations of "get" that I can find, but to no avail.

I'm totally new to Apps Script, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
function FloatEvents() {
    var calName = "AAAAAAA"; //The name of the calendar to modify
    var calID = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calName)[0].getId();
    var fromDate = new Date(Date.now() - 7*1000*3600*24);   //Start of the time range with events to be handled
    var untilDate = new Date(Date.now() + 1*1000*3600*24);    //End of the time range with events to be handled
    var optionalArgs = {
        timeMin: fromDate.toISOString(),
        timeMax: untilDate.toISOString(),
        showDeleted: false,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
    };
    var service = Calendar.Events;
    var response = Calendar.Events.list(calID, optionalArgs);
    var events = response.items;

    // ----- Loop thru period's events -----
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        Logger.log(events[i].getStartTime());  // <=== THIS RESULTS IN A "TypeError: Cannot find function getStartTime in object" ERROR
        // ----- Process event -----
        // Event update code goes here 
        // Will work on this once I solve the dates problem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you are getting the calendar ID through the CalendarApp, you are using Calendar API to retrieve Calendar Events, which returns an array of events (each one is a JSON object). To get the start and end time of each event, you have to access to their `start` and `end` properties in your loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var startTime = events[i].start.dateTime;
    var endTime = events[i].end.dateTime;
    console.log(startTime);
    console.log(endTime);
}
```

You can try the [API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it) to check what it is going to retrieve before start coding so you know the structure of the data you are going to work with.

However, if you want to use CalendarApp service instead of the Calendar API, you would have to call [getEvents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEvents(Date,Date,Object)) function, which returns a CalendarEvent array. These objects do have the [getStartTime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getStartTime()) function.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance - it helped me get past the error and make progress with my code.
I'm confused by the different possibilities provided by accessing via the API and via the Calendar App - can you suggest any resource that can help me understand the differences?

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/) is the only "comparison" I have found in their documentation. Advanced Google services (like the Calendar service you are using to retrieve events) use Google APIs, so they are more powerful than G Suite services (like CalendarApp)

Comment: @42 The REST APIs (advanced services) always return **data**, which may be "typed" to support property autocompletion with the dot/period operator. Data is almost always a JavaScript native object, e.g. a number, string, boolean, array, or generic object. To use them, you have to provide input data and identifiers to the method call. The native Apps Script services return **classes**, which have class- and instance-specific methods such as `Event#getStartTime()`, and occasionally data (e.g. the spreadsheet `Range#getValues()`).

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for the clarification. I see that I need to get a better understanding of JavaScript concepts and capabilities.